# Backup and Recover Table

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Database: Oracle 11g R2

Tool: TOAD for Oracle 10.6
```

I wanted to take backup of a table. Hence, I used the below query:

```
CREATE TABLE table_backup AS (

SELECT *

FROM table

);
```

I would require to make some changes to the table and restore it to the previous version after verifying the changes.

For that, I would DROP the table and restore it from its backup using the above query again.

My question is, when I do it, do all the grants, indexes, partitions, etc. remain in the restored table or not?

Also, is there a better way to achieve my requirement.

Comment: Unrelated but: the parentheses around the select are unnecessary and useless.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9003.htm) says:

> Dropping a table invalidates dependent objects and removes object privileges on the table. If you want to re-create the table, then you must regrant object privileges on the table, re-create the indexes, integrity constraints, and triggers for the table, and respecify its storage parameters.

Noen of the grants, indexes, partition etc. are moved or copied when you do you `create table as ... select` statement. There is no relationship between the original and copied tables. When you drop the original table all its grants etc. are lost. Renaming the backup table to the original doesn't magically restore them.

Other options include:

- export the original table including grants. After making your changes, drop the table and re-import it.
- rename your original table, which will retain the grants etc.; then recreate the table with the original name (maybe as a select from the renamed one). When you're done, drop the new table and rename the old one back to its original name. But be careful - don't get carried away and drop the real table by mistake. If your verification needs any of the grants etc. then you'd have to apply those to the new table; indexes would need different names which might complicate this.
- duplicate the table in a different schema (e.g. with export/import) and test you changes there, then throw it away. Again being careful about which copy you're working on/dropping. You can duplicate related tables if necessary to maintain integrity.
- drop the original table, recreate it, modify it and verify, then drop it again; and [use flashback drop](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24693_01/server.11203/e17120/tables011.htm#i1011362) to restore the original table. You need to be sure your flashback it set up to support this - so it has to be big enough to hold both dropped tables, for example. Fast but import/export might be safer.
- revert your individual changes one by one, which is risky if you're testing the changes - easy to miss something.

You also need to consider any referential constraints (PK/FK) and whether they would be affected by a rename or drop/recreate/export/import.